# Matrix Multiplication in Index Notation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to express the $i$ and $j$th component of the product $AB^{T}C$ in terms of the components of $A$, $B$ and $C$ in index notation/Einstein summation convention, where $A\in\Bbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $B\in\Bbb{R}^{q\times p}$ and $C\in\Bbb{R}^{q\times s}$.

I am aware of the standard notation for a supposed matrix product $C=AB$, which is $c_{ik}=a_{ij}b_{jk}$, but afterwards I am not sure how to proceed - appreciate any help I can get, thanks.

Comment: The standard notation you mention there is with a sigma sign of *sum* over $\;j\;$ .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use intermediate variables to avoid confusion

Define $D=B^T$ and $E=AD$ that way you want the $ij$th entry of $F=EC$

$$
d_{lm} = b_{ml}\\
e_{no} = a_{np} d_{po} = a_{np} b_{op}\\
f_{ij} = e_{ik} c_{kj} = a_{ip} b_{kp} c_{kj}
$$

By breaking down to each individual operation of multiplication/transposition it is easier. Use new names to keep track of everything to avoid confusion.

The first is swapping the entries because it is a transposition.

The next line is multiplication in index notation with $n$ $o$ and $p$ taking place of the dummy indices of $i$ $k$ and $j$ respectively. Then substitute the first line in for $d$'s entry.

The next line is multiplication for $E$ and $C$ and then substitute the second line for $e$'s entry.

P.S. for later, it is useful to have indices as superscripts and subscripts. It keeps track of rows vs columns for you and generalizes better.